# Is there a way to have Json.NET honor the System.Text.Json JsonPropertyName attribute

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, system.text.json

I have a C# type that represents a deserialized C# payload. But it's deserialized in one place by System.Text.Json. In another place, it's Json.NET.

So right now, I have to attribute the properties using both `[JsonProperty]` (for Json.NET) and `[JsonPropertyName]` (for System.Text.Json).

Is there a way to tell Json.NET recognize the JsonPropertyName attribute so I don't have to annotate each property twice?

Comment: [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) can indicate many things, not only the property name: the order, the required flag, etc. So you'll probably need to reimplement each aspect of it. If you only use it to indicate the property name, you could implement your own custom [Contract Resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm)

Comment: @thepirat000 the question is another way around - OP wants JSON.NET to handle `JsonPropertyNameAttribute`, which handles only name.

Comment: Oh you're right, sorry. So a Custom Contract Resolver should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) which will search for `JsonPropertyName` attribute and use value from it. Example one can look something like that:

```
public class ContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (member.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyNameAttribute>() is {} stj)
        {
            property.PropertyName = stj.Name;
            return property;
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("P1")]
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("P2")]
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new ContractResolver()
};  

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyClass(), settings)); // prints {"P1":0,"P2":0}
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>("{'P1':1,'P2':2}", settings).MyProperty2); // prints 2
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! In my case, I ended up annotating my objects with both because I'm passing them to other libraries and I can't control the serializers they're using.